# Date format changed on imported SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server

I have migrated a SQL Server database from one server to another. I did this via export to BAK and then Restore on the new machine.
Seems to be a different format somewhere, as a simple query that was working previously, is now throwing an error, but I cannot see what it might be (collation and 'containment' info seem the same).

**The old SQL Server version:** Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.6598.0 Express Edition

**The new SQL Server version:** Microsoft SQL Server 2019 - 15.0.2080.9 Express Edition

The error, below, refers to a date format:

```
 SELECT userID FROM tblLogin 
 WHERE CAST('30/09/2021 00:52:14' AS datetime) < DATEADD(n,600,accessDate)
```

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

(Column `accessDate` is of type datetime, null)

Comment: Date (and time) data types don't have a format, so the "format" changing is impossible. The *real* problem is you're using an ambiguous literal string format and (presumably) using a different language setting. When ever using literal strings for dates values **always** use an unambiguous format; there are 2 in SQL Server: `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`.

Comment: Language or country settings of the server.

Comment: Also, your function is in the wrong place. The `DATEADD` should be on the literal, not the column, to maintain SARGability.

Comment: You have a good explanation below, but as to the different behaviour have you checked the *local* settings of the OS to make sure they are identical between old and new server.

Comment: @Stu - Thanks. Previous server was in the US, current one in UK. I have changed the new server's Country/Region to the US and Regional Format to English US. That hasn't done the trick though. is there another setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always *always* **ALWAYS** use the ISO-8601 date formats for literals in Sql Server. For historical reasons, the preferred option for date-only values is different than date-time values, so you want either `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` for date and time or `yyyyMMdd` for date-only. But the really important thing is **always** go in order from most significant (year) to least significant (second).

Anything else isn't really a date literal at all: it's a string you must convert to a date.

If we follow this *correct* convention (because anything else really is *incorrect*), you get it down to this (which doesn't even need the `CAST()` anymore, because Sql Server can interpret it as datetime from the beginning):

```
SELECT userID 
FROM tblLogin 
WHERE accessDate > DATEADD(n, -600, '2021-09-30T00:52:14')
```

Also note I inverted the check, moving the `DATEADD()` function to act on the literal, instead of the column. This is always preferred, because it can work with any index you may have on the `accessDate` column. The original code would have rendered any such index worthless for this query.

Comment: The "safe" format with the date and time parts actually needs to be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` with a capital `T` separating the date and time portions. The one without the `T` can have troubles converting to `DATETIME` depending on your language/dateformat setings ..... see [Aaron's great post on this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe) on dba.se

Comment: Thank you. Is the 1st date option to suggested he same as `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` as was mentioned above in a comment?

Comment: @kneidels Yes, they are the same, just without the partial seconds.

Comment: @marc_s Ooops, yeah :)